# Kubernetes NodeJS consuming more than 1 CPU?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

We are running a single NodeJS instance in a Pod with a request of 1 CPU, and no limit. Upon load testing, we observed the following:

```
NAME                                                CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
backend-deployment-5d6d4c978-5qvsh                  3346m        103Mi
backend-deployment-5d6d4c978-94d2z                  3206m        99Mi
```

If NodeJS is only running a single thread, how could it be consuming more than 1000m CPU, when running directly on a Node it would only utilize a single core? Is kubernetes somehow letting it borrow time across cores?

Comment: 1. It's a cumulative consumption from all containers within a pod. Are you sure you have only one container per pod? 2. It's userland only in nodejs that is single threaded, but under the hood nodejs is pretty much multithreaded

Comment: Yes I am sure it's a single container per pod. I am basically hammer these guys with 450 req/s where they are calculating whether an argon2 hash is a certain password.

Comment: @zerkms How is it multithreaded under the hood?

Comment: nodejs is a C++ application, and it's multithreaded.

Comment: @zerkms node only uses a thread pool for very specific operations for which there is no good async io primitives from the OS. for instance it doesn’t use a thread pool for network io.

Comment: @arg20 I'm not sure I'm following your point. Do you argue nodejs **is** multithreaded?

Comment: @zerkms I’m arguing that node.js is only seldomly multithreaded. Except for some file io and crypto functions or dns resolution, almost all the rest of the operations are not multithreaded. Just trying to put an asterisk next to “nodejs… it’s multithreaded”

Answer (score 4):

Although Node.js runs the main application code in a single thread, the Node.js runtime is multi-threaded.  Node.js has an internal [worker pool](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/) that is used to run background tasks, including I/O and certain CPU-intensive processing like crypto functions.  In addition, if you use the [worker_threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) facility (not to be confused with the worker pool), then you would be directly accessing additional threads in Node.js.

Comment: https://medium.com/pipedrive-engineering/how-we-choked-our-kubernetes-nodejs-services-932acc8cc2be recommends using 1.15 CPU cores

Comment: No, they say to set the limit higher than 1 and since node has additional workers the say 4 should eliminate all throttling